# dictionary and stack in python problem

Tags: python, stack

I have made a dictionary and I put the keys of the dict in a list. My list contains elements like this:

```
s =  [((5, 4), 'South', 1), ((4, 5), 'West', 1)]
```

I made a dict from this:

```
child = dict((t[0], t[1]) for t in s)

keys = child.keys()
print keys
```

The output is : `[(4, 5), (5, 4)]`

Now I need to put (4,5) and (5,4) into stack. What should I do?

I tried, but when I do pop from the stack it is giving me the 2 elements together. 
like stack.pop() - `output is : [(4, 5), (5, 4)]`. I want to pop one by one... (4,5) and then (5,4)

Comment: could you clarify? what are you doing, what is it doing that you think is wrong, and what would you like it to do?

Comment: Where/What is the stack?

Comment: plz see the question again...i have made changes

Comment: i don't get it. `[(4,5),(5,4)].pop()` returns `(5,4)` ...

Comment: This question needs a lot of clarification. I wish that SO had a template for asking questions, with sections like "What I tried" and "What it should look like".

Comment: @jesse: good idea. post it on meta and link here so i can upvote it! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think user wants this:

```
# python
> stack = [(4, 5), (5, 4)]
> stack.pop(0)
(4,5)
> stack.pop(0)
(5,4)
```

Just a reminder, though, this is *not* a proper stack. This is a proper stack:

```
# python
> stack=[]
> stack.append( (4,5) )    
> stack.append( (5,4) )
> stack.pop()
(5,4)
> stack.pop()
(4,5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list as a stack:

```
stack = list(child.keys())
print stack.pop()
print stack.pop()
```

Result:

```
(5, 4)
(4, 5)
```

Important note: the keys of a dictionary are not ordered so if you want the items in a specific order you need to handle that yourself. For example if you want them in normal sorted order you could use `sorted`. If you want them to pop off in reverse order from the order they were in `s` you could skip the conversion to a dictionary and just go straight from `s` to your stack:

```
stack = [x[0] for x in s]
print stack.pop()
print stack.pop()
```

Result:

```
(4, 5)
(5, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
element = stack[0]
if len(stack) > 0:
   stack = stack[1:]

print element
```

but it is not that kind of a stack :/

Comment: @shilpa, pushing and popping on a list *is* a proper stack. push puts on the end, pop removes from the end.

Comment: it is basicaly the same, you can "wrap" this in a own class and call it stack (with your function names and so on)